# Fluent NHibernate - convention to apply custom type

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate (Auto Mapping) to map my domain objects to database tables.  I've created my own 'Date' class which I map using 'DateTranslator' - an implementation of NHibernate's 'IUserType'.

```
public class MyDomainObject : DomainObject
{
    public Date Date { get; set; }
}

public class MyDomainObjectMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<MyDomainObject>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<MyDomainObject> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.Date).CustomType(typeof(DateTranslator));
    }
}
```

As you can see - I've created a mapping override for this domain object so that I can specify the custom type that should be used to map the 'Date' property.

Now - this means that I'll have to create a mapping override for all domain objects that contain a property of type 'Date'.

I'd like to use a convention here so that 'DateTranslator' will be used to map all properties of type 'Date' but I've been unable to figure it out.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyUsertypeConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type.Name == "Date")
        //or
        //if (instance.Type.GetUnderlyingSystemType() == typeof(Date))
            instance.CustomType<DateTranslator>();
    }
}
```

and config for example

```
FluentMappings.Conventions.Add(new MyUsertypeConvention())
```

Comment: Won't work if a property you try to apply custom type to is considered to be a reference by default.

Comment: then you forgot to exclude the custom type from automapping. `override bool ShouldMap(t) { return t != typeof(Date) && base.ShouldMap(t); }`

Comment: I'm having problems with this too. It seems that ShouldMap(Type type) is never called for my property which has a custom primitive type, but it also isn't hitting my IPropertyConvention. Anything obvious that I might have missed?

Comment: @DavGarcia there are 2 ShouldMap() methods, one for types and one for properties. You should override the one for types and also check that IsComponent() is not true for this type otherwise FNH will automap it as Component(); if this doesn't help ask a new question with more info and let me know